# I want to know If GTX 1050 Ti is using or not?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I bought a notebook (My notebook : https://www.monsternotebook.com.tr/abra/MONSTER-ABRA-A5-V9-2-3.html#.WsnRdOZRXCI ) last week.I installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with doing dual boot.

In Windows, I know that my graphic card GTX 1050 Ti is used(active).

But in Ubuntu, I don't know if it is active or not? How can I learn this?
And if it is not active , how can I active it?

`prime-select query`  this give me a output like this :

`unknown`

`sudo prime-select intel` give me a output like this:

`Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', None]
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Error: the installed packages do not support PRIME
Error: intel mode can't be enabled`

(same output for nvdia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the terminal:

```
prime-select query
```

This will answer "intel" or "nvidia", that's the one in use. To switch without need to reboot or anything:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

the parameter here can be either "intel" or "nvidia".

Comment: please see edited question

Comment: I can only make speculiations on that outut.
Maybe is an old version of OS (you're on 16.04 right?) that along with old kernel, mesa, intel and nvidia drivers, just do not support prime properly.  Update to 17.10 or to 18.04 LTS in a few weeks is indeed a good options, I am on 17.10 myself and Steam works properly, as well as prime with nvidia/intel combination

Answer (score 0):

I installed `prime-select` in a computer with 16.04 LTS using an (old) nvidia card, but it responds 'unknown' (while it can be expected to work in newer versions of Ubuntu).

Maybe you find what you want via **`lshw`** in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
$ LANG=C sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for sudodus: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108 [GeForce GT 430]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:40:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:25 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:1000(size=128) memory:fb080000-fb0fffff
```

In my computer it shows

- the hardware `product: GF108 [GeForce GT 430]`
- the software `configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0`

  I'm using the built-in linux driver `nouveau`, which actually works better for me than a proprietary driver with this nvidia card.